# Convenção de commits

Tags: git, react-native, github, commit

Estou iniciando um novo projeto e gostaria de seguir as convenções de commits. Dei uma lida na documentação, mas surgiu uma dúvida em qual type usar na hora de fazer o meu primeiro commit.

No meu primeiro commit contempla apenas a instalação do React Native com TypeScript.

Gostaria de saber qual **type**(feat, ci ou chore) seria o correto para esse tipo de commit.

git commit -m "type: Inicialização do projeto"

Comment: build? Eu achei uma pagina sobre isso. Nem sabia o que era. Interessante. https://dev.to/renatoadorno/padroes-de-commits-commit-patterns-41co

Comment: Pelo que tenho pesquisado o pessoal tem usado mais o chore mesmo quando se lida somente com configurações iniciais, mas não tenho certeza se é o correto.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar seguir o padrão apontado pelo site conventional commits:

https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/

No seu caso, seria "feat: Inicializando o projeto" ou "feat: Commit inicial"

Comment: Obrigado Felipe